# converting induction cook top wiring into plug

Tags: wiring, stove

I recently had my induction cooktop die, and I am looking at getting a new one. However I noticed that the old cook top was simply connected with a standard 2 prong EU plug (I am in Finland). When my new cook top came, it came with 3 wires instead of plug. Is it possible to wire that into a plug? Or do I need to redo the wiring to accept the new connection?

My new cook top is a Miele KM 7000 KM7201FR

[image: The outlet]
[image: The Old plug]
[image: The new stove wires]
Thanks

Comment: It may be possible if you can take a photo of the electrical behind the plug there may be a safety or earth ground there already.

Comment: Not sure how to upload photos, but it is a standard EU socket so it has the connectors for the ground. Also since it was used with the previous cooktop, I assume it is OK. My other concern is that the new wires are much thicker than the old ones, does this indicate anything?

Comment: What do the instructions say about installing the cook top?

Comment: If by thicker you the metal wire itself, not just the covering, then quite possible you need a new larger circuit with a larger breaker.  Main thing you need to know is the ampage of the new stove.  Most house circuits are split into normal  low amps, like lights, toasters, and higher amps like stoves, dryers, water heaters.  A small stove might work at low amps, but a big stove needs more amps and it's own circuit.

Comment: Do you know what the power requirement of the old cooktop vs. new is?

Comment: Wester, you can edit and add photos click on the mountain in the square, I think I remember that. Our receptacles here on this side of the pond are sized by amperage and voltage as they increase the plug gets larger so we can’t plug a low amperage device into a high amp socket, from memory I remember fuses locally at the switches or cords but I was only in a few residential type homes when I was there. Aren’t your larger circuits only 16 or 18 amps? 220-240v.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I've now added photos to the post. As for the amps, I can't really figure it out, where should I look? I just see the wattage around 7000, and the voltage is 200-230V

Answer (score 1):

You can. But you probably do not want to.

Schuko is fused at max 16A, so you can never pull more than 3.2kW over a Schuko plug. I do not know the electric code in Finland, so it may not be legal to connect machines that can draw a larger current to a Schuko as well.

To use your 7kW cooking top, you will need a 32A circuit breaker if the top is single phase. This means rewiring with thicker wire and replacing the outlet with a different type that can handle 32A.

To wire it (temporarily), you can go to a store that sells electric products, such as Biltema. What you're looking for is [a schuko plug](https://www.biltema.fi/rakentaminen/sahkoasennustarvikkeet/pistotulpat/pistotulppa-maadoitettu-2000017389). Biltema is just an example, as I know they are present in Finland, and the article numbers are the same as in Norway, so it is easy for me to link. Connect the blue and brown wire to the prongs, and the yellow/green to the earth symbol.

This should only be regarded as temporary fix, until you can get an electrician to update your installation.

Comment: Nit:  16A at 220V is 3.5kW, not 3.2.  Also, the OP's photo shows the connection cable for the new top, and has neutral, ground, and a single phase.  (So definitely need 32A.)

Comment: Also, please indicate what "this" is that you've linked to. Not everyone speaks Finnish, and links do die, leaving that a useless link in the future. I'd suggest that you need a TL;DR: at the top saying, effectively "you likely need to have an electrician run a new circuit", which is what it's sounding like to me.